# Не работает всплывающее окно с редактированием

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Здравствуйте! 
Есть таблица workers [id/steamid/wallet]. При нажатии на кнопку "редактировать" открывается всплывающее окно для редактирования. Вот только id в обработчике не ловится. 
Если, например, совсем извратиться и в адресной строке дописать "?red_id=1", то все работает.При нажатии на редактировать открывается всплыв окно и там редактирование пользователя с этим id,а если просто нажать "редактировать",от откроется пустое окно
Но почему id не передается?
Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться.

```
    <?php 
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION["session_username"])) {
    header("location:login.php");
} 
?>


<?php include("includes/header.php"); ?>
<head>




 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
    $( function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
  } );
  </script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() { // вся магия после загрузки страницы
    $('a#go').click( function(event){ // ловим клик по ссылки с id="go"
        event.preventDefault(); // выключаем стандартную роль элемента
        $('#overlay').fadeIn(400, // сначала плавно показываем темную подложку
            function(){ // после выполнения предъидущей анимации
                $('#modal_form') 
                    .css('display', 'block') // убираем у модального окна display: none;
                    .animate({opacity: 1, top: '50%'}, 200); // плавно прибавляем прозрачность одновременно со съезжанием вниз
        });
    });
    /* Закрытие модального окна, тут делаем то же самое но в обратном порядке */
    $('#modal_close, #overlay').click( function(){ // ловим клик по крестику или подложке
        $('#modal_form')
            .animate({opacity: 0, top: '45%'}, 200,  // плавно меняем прозрачность на 0 и одновременно двигаем окно вверх
                function(){ // после анимации
                    $(this).css('display', 'none'); // делаем ему display: none;
                    $('#overlay').fadeOut(400); // скрываем подложку
                }
            );
    });
});
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() { // вся магия после загрузки страницы
    $('a#go2').click( function(event){ // ловим клик по ссылки с id="go"
        event.preventDefault(); // выключаем стандартную роль элемента
        $('#overlay2').fadeIn(400, // сначала плавно показываем темную подложку
            function(){ // после выполнения предъидущей анимации
                $('#modal_form2') 
                    .css('display', 'block') // убираем у модального окна display: none;
                    .animate({opacity: 1, top: '50%'}, 200); // плавно прибавляем прозрачность одновременно со съезжанием вниз
        });
    });
    /* Закрытие модального окна, тут делаем то же самое но в обратном порядке */
    $('#modal_close2, #overlay2').click( function(){ // ловим клик по крестику или подложке
        $('#modal_form2')
            .animate({opacity: 0, top: '45%'}, 200,  // плавно меняем прозрачность на 0 и одновременно двигаем окно вверх
                function(){ // после анимации
                    $(this).css('display', 'none'); // делаем ему display: none;
                    $('#overlay2').fadeOut(400); // скрываем подложку
                }
            );
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body style='overflow-x:hidden;'>

        <div id="tabs"> 

    <ul>

    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Список работяг</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Ваши жертвы</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">Свободные игроки</a></li>
    </ul>
    <a href="logout.php"><img class="img" src="exit.png"  alt="" ></a>

<div id="tabs-1"> 

  <?php
   $host="localhost";
    $user="root";
    $pass=""; //установленный вами пароль
    $db_name="pubg";
    $link=mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);
    mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
    mysql_select_db($db_name,$link);


    $username=$_POST['username1'];
    $password=$_POST['password1'];
  $steamid=$_POST['steamid1'];
  $wallet=$_POST['wallet1'];

  if (isset($_GET['del_id'])) { //проверяем, есть ли переменная на удаление
        $sql = mysql_query('DELETE FROM `workers` WHERE `id` = '.$_GET['del_id']); //удаляем строку из таблицы
    }

     if (isset($_GET['del_id2'])) { //проверяем, есть ли переменная на удаление
        $sql = mysql_query('DELETE FROM `users` WHERE `id` = '.$_GET['del_id2']); //удаляем строку из таблицы
        header("Location: /admin/intropage.php#tabs-3");
    }


  if (isset($_POST['red_id'])) { //Проверяем, передана ли переменная на редактирования
        if (isset($_POST['username'])) { //Если новое имя предано, то обновляем и имя и цену
            $sql = mysql_query('UPDATE `workers` SET '
                    .'`username` = "'.$_POST['username'].'",'
                    .'`steamid` = '.$_POST['steamid'].', '
                    .'`wallet` = '.$_POST['wallet'].' '
                    .'WHERE `id` = '.$_POST['red_id']);
        }
    }       

     if (isset($_POST["username1"])) {
    //Вставляем данные, подставляя их в запрос
    $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `workers` (`group`, `steamid`,`wallet`,`username`,`password`) 
                        VALUES (0,'$steamid','$wallet','$username','$password')");
      header("Location: /admin/intropage.php");
      }

        ?>



        <div id="modal_form">
      <span id="modal_close"><img src="icon.png" id="modal_close" alt=""></span> 

      <p class="p8">Добавление работяги :)</p>
        <table>
        <form name="" method="post" action="">
    <tr>
        <p class="tdd">Логин:</p>
        <input type="text" class="td2"  name="username1">
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <p class="tdd2">Пароль:</p>
        <input type="text" class="td3" name="password1">
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <p class="tdd3">Steam ID:</p>
        <input type="text" class="td4"  name="steamid1">
    </tr>
    <p class="tdd4">Wallet:</p>
        <input type="text"  class="td5" name="wallet1">
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><button class="knopka2" >OK</button></td>
    </tr>
</form>
</table>
</div>
<div id="overlay"></div> 




  <button class="knopka"><a href="#" id="go">Добавить</a></button>

   <table border='1'>
<tr>
    <th>Имя</th>
    <th>Steam ID</th>
    <th>ID</th>
</tr> 

    <?php
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT `id`, `username`, `steamid`, `wallet` FROM `workers`", $link);
    while ($result = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
      if ($result['steamid'] == 0 )
        $result['steamid']='Отсутствует';
    echo     '<tr><td>'.$result['username'].'</td>'.
             '<td>'.$result['steamid'].'</td>'.
             '<td>'.$result['id'].'</td>'.
             '<td><button class="buton3"><a href="?del_id='.$result['id'].'" >Удолить</a></button></td>'.
             '<td><button class="buton3"><a href="?red_id='.$result['id'].'" id="go2"  >Редактировать</a></button></td></tr>';


}
?>

</table>
<div id="modal_form2"><!-- Сaмo oкнo -->
    <span id="modal_close2"><img src="icon.png" id="modal_close2" alt=""></span> 
    <!-- Тут сoдержимoе -->
    <?php
    $host="localhost";    
    $user="root";       
    $pass="goldberg";           
    $db_name="pubg";    
    $link=mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass); 
    mysql_select_db($db_name,$link);       
    if (isset($_POST['red_id'])) {
        $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `workers` WHERE `id`=".$_GET['red_id'], $link);
        $result = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
        ?>
        <table>
            <form action="" method="post">
                <tr>
                    <input type="hidden" name="red_id" value="<?php echo ($result['red_id']); ?>">
        <td>Имя:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo ($result['username']); ?>"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Steam ID:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="steamid"  value="<?php echo ($result['steamid']); ?>"></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Wallet:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="wallet"  value="<?php echo ($result['wallet']); ?>"></td>
    </tr>

                    <td colspan="2"><button class="knopka2" >OK</button></td>
                </tr>
            </form>
        </table>
        <?php
    }
    ?>
</div>
<div id="overlay2"></div><!-- Пoдлoжкa -->



</div>
 <div id="tabs-2">
hey 





  </div>



  <div id="tabs-3"> 


    <ul>
    <li>ID</li>
    <li>Имя</li>
    <li>SteamID</li>
    </ul>

    <div class="box">
        <div class="box-scroll">
            <table id="tbl2">

<?php
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT `id`, `name`, `steamid` FROM `users`", $link);    
    while ($result = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {

    echo     '<tr><td>'.$result['id'].'</td>'.
             '<td>'.$result['name'].'</td>'.
             '<td><a class="a1" href="http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/'.$result['steamid'].'" target="_blank">'.$result['steamid'].'</a></td>'.
             '<td><button class="buton3"><a href="?del_id2='.$result['id'].'" >Удолить</a></button></td></tr>';


}

?>
</div>
</div>
</table>


    </div>




</body>
```

Comment: как же будет работать если у Вас все запросы к бд на одной странице? Вызывайте через ajax удаленно, выполняйте запрос и открывайте модальное окно с полученными данными. А так Вы попросту открываете блок с тем что у Вас уже есть на странице.

Comment: не понял,ну я подключил обработчик,в который добавил скрипт самого всплыв.окна,изменил код js также,но теперь форма даже не открывается

Comment: Сейчас Вы создаете страницу в которой уже есть скрытая форма со всеми данными. И все запросы к бд уже выполнены. При нажатии на ссылку у Вас форма просто становится видимой. А для получения актуальных данных для редактирования конкретного `worker` Вам нужно отправить запрос на сервер  с id работника, получить данные и поставить данные в форму редактирования в модальном окне, после чего отобразить модальное окно. А подставляя `red_id` в адрес Вы всего лишь получаете информацию на **этой** странице для конкретного `red_id`.

Comment: можете пожалуйста написать код,который отправляет этот запрос ?

Comment: https://jquery-docs.ru/jQuery.ajax/   https://goo.gl/LMsk3y

Answer (score 0):

Стоит попробовать добавить в форму скрытый input со значением "red_id". И в php проверять $_POST, а не $_GET.

Comment: Не совсем понял по-поводу скрытого инпута,как это сделать ?Можете отредактировать мой код пожалуйста ?

Comment: В форму, там где есть другие input, можно добавить скрытое поле: <input type="hidden" name="red_id" value="<?php echo ($result['red_id']); ?>">

Comment: И в PHP, где if (isset($_GET['red_id'])) {, проверять $_POST['red_id']

Comment: Дело в том, что запрос на сервер отправляет кнопка OK ".knopka2". Поэтому отправляются только те данные, которые есть в форме. А кнопка "Редактировать" и ее аргумент red_id не попадают в форму.

Comment: добавил скрытое поле,поменял GET на POST,не помогло (((

Comment: выкладывайте тест. надо же оценить обновление

Comment: выложил полный код с изменениями

Comment: в примере, в форме, нет добавленного поля  <input type="hidden" name="red_id" value="<?php echo ($result['red_id']); ?>">

Comment: И там, где выполняется обработка запроса на редактирование if (isset($_POST['red_id'])), остался лишний $_GET

Comment: я не тот код редактировал,сейчас добавил то,что на данный момент.Все равно не работает

Comment: В форме, в скрытом поле, скорее всего надо value="<?php echo($result[ 'id' ]); ?>"

Comment: Изменил value,не работает

Comment: после кликак по кнопке OK, в форме, запрос вообще доходит до if (isset($_POST['red_id'])) ...?

Comment: @psaproxy распишите, основываясь на листинге Ивана Иванова,ответ с примером.

Comment: @psaproxy как узнать доходит или нет ?

Comment: можно использовать подобную функцию для записи лога https://pastebin.com/Tvv7efqW

Comment: можете написать подробно,что туда вписывать пожалуйста ?